# ASPNetBoilerPlate and Swagger UI All API Calls Return 400 Error

Tags: swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate

I have created a new application using the ASPNetBoilerplate MVC 5x template. I have integrated Swagger UI according to the link:

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Swagger-UI-Integration

Again using the MVC 5x version

When I run the app and use http://localhost:/swagger to access the API and try to run any of the GetAll methods, I get a 400 error.

I have modified the .cs file and created the .js files by cutting the code directly from the documentation and made the required changes.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not navigating to **http://localhost:/swagger**  because there's a typo error. Correct url is **http://localhost/swagger**

Comment: The application runs.  It looks like the security is not being added into the request

Comment: you mean authentication token? do you see the landing page of swagger

Comment: Yes, I can see the toggle page, but I get a 400 error whenever I try to run any of the API methods

Comment: Sorry, I mean the swagger page.  Should I be able to set a break point to debug this in the WebApiModule class?  I tried to debug the .js file, but it was either ignored, or was not run.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's no official support for bearer token for Swagger UI Api calls. But you can checkout the link below. A developer achieves what you want

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/87